# How to report a error to user without raising a exception from middleware in Django

Tags: django, middleware

**my middleware**

```
def password_validator_middleware(get_response):
    def my_function(request):
        #converting bytes typeto dictionary type
        dict_str = request.body.decode("UTF-8")
        details_entered = ast.literal_eval(dict_str)
        #checking if that password exist in the database
        if pwned_passwords_django.api.pwned_password(details_entered['password']):
           return
        else:
            print("your password looks fine")
        response = get_response(request)
        return response
    return my_function
```

Here if password entered is a pwned password i want to return and say to user that your password is pwned how can i do that , i want to return from there only without going ahead from the middleware

Comment: You can return whatever response you like from your middleware. Why a middleware though? Are users going to be submitting their password on every request?

Comment: No, its just a password validator so that it raises a error on every user weak or compromised password, middleware is just used to increase the efficiency